# What is the space of all square-integrable periodic functions?

Tags: functional-analysis

Is there a specific name to the space of all functions in $L^2$, specifically over 1-dimensional Euclidean space, with a specific periodicity (let's say $a$ in the 1-dimensional Euclidean space case).

[please correct the tag(s) if they are wrong]

Comment: Do you mean functions on $\mathbb{R}$ for which $f(x+a)=f(x)$ for all $x$? In this case only the zero function (or rather, it's class) is in $L^2$. However, we usually identify periodic functions on $\mathbb{R}$ with periodic functions on the circle. The norm becomes something like the $L^2$-norm *restricted to $[0,a]$*, instead of the $L^2$-norm on $\mathbb{R}$. This space is sometimes denote $P_a(\mathbb{R})$, $L^2[0,a]$ (if no confusion arises from this) or variants, but I don't think there is a common, specific name for it.

Comment: @LuizCordeiro Yes that is what I meant. That distinction is important (otherwise yeah, what I say is nonsense).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the torodial $L^2$ space
$$ L^2(\mathbb{T})
$$
where $\mathbb{T} = \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is the unit torus.